# How to repeat the background image for UITextView in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working on a project in that I face a problem, I gave the background image for UITextView when I scroll the UITextView the image is repeating not fixed,so please tell any idea to fixed the UIImage for UITextView.

[image]
Regards,
Raja.I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Image.png"]];
```

Comment: s i added but i'm getting like this

Answer (score 0):

```
    Use following instance method of UIImage

    - (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets
```

It will return you resized image which will not repeat. Available in iOS 5.0 and later. You can get more help on same from documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this.
set the textView background color to clear and add UIImageView with your background image as a subview before the UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

refer this link [repeat image](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html)

```
UIImage* mars = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Mars.png"];
UIImage* marsTiled = [mars resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                   CGRectMake(20,5,mars.size.width,mars.size.height*4)];
//image width is equal to text field width

iv.image = marsTiled;
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:iv];
```